# Ruby: How to capitalize the first line only in a string

Tags: ruby

I can not seem to get how to capitalize just the first line of a string

```
"1. walking down the street
2. to go to the store
3. to buy some groceries"
```

Comment: Define "first line" and "capitalize"

Comment: Show the expected output..

Comment: It will have no effect on a string that starts with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub) replaces only the first match. Using this feature:

```
>> s = "1. walking down the street
2. to go to the store
3. to buy some groceries"

>> puts s.sub(/.*/, &:upcase)
1. WALKING DOWN THE STREET
2. to go to the store
3. to buy some groceries

>> puts s.sub(/.*/) { |line| line.sub(/[a-z]/i, &:upcase) }
1. Walking down the street
2. to go to the store
3. to buy some groceries
```

---

**UPDATE** according to the comment:

```
>> puts s.gsub(/.*/) { |line| line.sub(/[a-z]/i, &:upcase) }
1. Walking down the street
2. To go to the store
3. To buy some groceries
```

Comment: the output is suppose to look like this: "1. Walking down the street
2. To go to the store
3. To buy some groceries"

Comment: @user3263521, See the update. You said **just the first line of a string**. Please update the words in the question (with expected output)

Answer (score 0):

**INPUT:**

```
1. walking down the street
2. to go to the store
3. to buy some groceries
```

**Use this:**

```
.sub(/[a-zA-Z]/){|c| c.upcase}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1. Walking down the street
2. to go to the store
3. to buy some groceries
```